# How to control html videos by mouse scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I have to implement videos tags on my HTML page.i have included one video in video tag but if i scroll up the video should be forward how much i have scrolled and if i scroll down the video should be backward and it should play.i have tried like this.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function updateVideo() {
        var video = $('#one').get(0);
        var videoLength = video.duration;
        var scrollPosition = $(document).scrollTop();
        video.currentTime = (scrollPosition / ($(document).height() - $(window).height())) * videoLength;//(scrollPosition / SCROLL_SCRUB_SPEED) % videoLength;
    }

    $(window).scroll(function(e) {
             if(videoReady && continueUpdatingVideo) { updateVideo(); }
     });


</script>
```

and html is

```
 <div class="container">
    <video id="one" width="480" height="600" autoplay loop controls class="hello">
            <source type="video/mp4" src="https://d3mlfyygrfdi2i.cloudfront.net/fd77/team_04022013_b_v4.mp4"></source>
            <source  type="video/webm" src="https://d3mlfyygrfdi2i.cloudfront.net/c943/team_04022013_b_v4.webm" ></source>
            You need an HTML5 capable browser to view this video.
    </video>
</div>
```

Comment: And so what's the problem?

Comment: Can you try rewriting the question to make it more clear what issues you are having with this approach?

Answer (score 2):

You will probably want to use the "mousewheel" event instead of the "scroll" event. The "scroll" event only fires when the viewport actually moves.

Here's a jsFiddle to see the scrolling portion in action http://jsfiddle.net/33m33/.

I think this script should do what you're needing, though you may need to make a couple of modifications:

```
var video = $('#one').get(0);
var increments = 2; //steps two seconds for each scroll event
var videoReady = false; //set to true when video loads
var continueUpdatingVideo = false;

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#one').bind('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();

      if(videoReady && continueUpdatingVideo) {
        var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -e.originalEvent.detail))); //either +1 or -1
        updateVideo(delta * increments);
      }

      return false;
  });
});

function updateVideo(delta) {
  var videoLength = video.duration;
  var videoPosition = (video.currentTime + delta > videoLength) ? videoLength : ((video.currentTime + delta < 0) ? 0 : video.currentTime + delta);
  video.currentTime = videoPosition;
}
```