# How can I get my jQuery function to run inside of another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help understanding why my jquery inside of forty is not working. I am working to create a virtual microscope and when the user clicks an image of 40x, I want a video to be displayed and be able to use mouse scroll to skim through the video. I found this piece of code at [How to control html videos by mouse scroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23931746/how-to-control-html-videos-by-mouse-scroll) to get the skimming aspect through a video with mouse scroll. It works fine if it is in a separate file by itself, but inside the forty function, it will not work. I need the function to be triggered when the user clicks the image so I am not sure how I can do that without having it inside a function. I have been using javascript with this project and have done little to no work in jquery, any direction would be awesome!

```
   <video id="cellvid" autoplay loop>
         <source type="video/mp4" src="media/micVideo.mp4"></source>
   </video>

   <img class="mag" id="40x" src="img/invertMag40x.png" alt="" onclick="forty()">
```

```
function forty() {

    var video = $('#cellvid').get(0);
    var increments = 0.5;
    var videoReady=true;
    var continueUpdatingVideo=true;

    jQuery.event.special.mousewheel = {
        setup: function( _, ns, handle ){
            this.addEventListener("mousewheel", handle, { passive: true });
        }
    };

    //uses mousewheel Eventlistener
    $(function(){
        $('#cellvid').on('mousewheel', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log("I made it inside");

            if(videoReady && continueUpdatingVideo) {
                var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -e.originalEvent.detail))); //either +1 or -1
                updateVideo(delta * increments);
                console.log("Mouse Scroll");
            }
            return false;
        });
    });


    function updateVideo(delta) {
        var videoLength = video.duration;
        var videoPosition = (video.currentTime + delta > videoLength) ? videoLength : ((video.currentTime + delta < 0) ? 0 : video.currentTime + delta);
        video.currentTime = videoPosition;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- You need to separate the function definitions.
- For example the event listener should be **defined outside** the `forty()`
- Also the `updateVideo(delta)` needs to be **defined outside** and invoked inside `forty()`.
- Following is somewhat how you could chnage it to get it closer to working, make changes as needed, like passing delta while calling `updateVideo()`

```js
function forty() {
  var video = $('#cellvid').get(0);
  var increments = 0.5;
  var videoReady = true;
  var continueUpdatingVideo = true;

  jQuery.event.special.mousewheel = {
    setup: function(_, ns, handle) {
      this.addEventListener("mousewheel", handle, {
        passive: true
      });
    }
  };
  updateVideo(someInputHere); // <-- change the function input here 
}

//uses mousewheel Eventlistener
$(function() {
  $('#cellvid').on('mousewheel', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("I made it inside");

    if (videoReady && continueUpdatingVideo) {
      var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -e.originalEvent.detail))); //either +1 or -1
      updateVideo(delta * increments);
      console.log("Mouse Scroll");
    }
    return false;
  });
});


function updateVideo(delta) {
  var videoLength = video.duration;
  var videoPosition = (video.currentTime + delta > videoLength) ? videoLength : ((video.currentTime + delta < 0) ? 0 : video.currentTime + delta);
  video.currentTime = videoPosition;
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it did not work. Thank you for the comment though!